# How do you clear the cache?

Tags: cache

So I have been having trouble with this blend file I am working on, different parts of the animation process keep glitching and very inconsistently. For instance if I run an animation I have made the leg of the character might spasm, but if I change the current animation I'm viewing to another and then back to the orginal after it's fixed till I load it again and the glitch is back.
Someone suggested this
@Edgel3D
When these inexplicable glitches occur I find the cure is often in saving the file to another filename, exit Blender altogether, delete any cache files it makes, (usually in the current project folder) and also any quit and other files in Blender's temp folder. (as setup in User Pref's) Reload your new Blend file.

They disappeared before I could get further information. SO how do I delete the files cache as well as the the ones in blenders temp folder?
I tried searching for the answer on her and google and none of the ways I phrased it got an an answer.

Comment: As far as I know there is no "cache" that I am aware of. Blender writes very little to disk beyond the file itself and a bunch autosaves in temp

Comment: When I'm using physics, particles, or the VSE I get cache files and I find them in the current project's folder as a rule.  They do tend to cling and affect subsequent loads and that's why I delete them and re-save under a different Blender filename, temporarily at least.  The cache files are in fact a folder with the title "Blender_Cache_Files" or similar.  I'm talking version 2.77a which is getting a bit out of date. 2.8 may do things differently.  Speaking from memory here I think you can elect where the particles cache goes, either 'externally' (to the drive) or not.

Comment: Further to the above, if you can't find these files, perhaps it's due to some interaction?  (Modifiers, constraints, physics etc)  You could try saving to a new filename and deleting or disabling other elements one at a time, see of it clears up.

Comment: Any time I've encountered "spasming" like you describe, tabbing in and out of Edit Mode has fixed it for me. I think changing frames will do it as well. Can happen when you have a lot of parent-child hierarchy going on and modifiers affecting the positions of those objects.

Comment: I can't find the folder for the specific project which is flustering because I could have sworn a couple weeks ago I stumbled into it during a search for location of the actual blend file itself.
Also Mentalist I tried you suggestion with out affect.
(Edit) I just stumbled across something strange, I don't know if it matters but when I play the animation backwards it works perfectly despite it spasming when I play it forwards.

Comment: I think there's gotta be some kind of cache Blender is using, particularly around modifiers. I've created the same mesh deform modifier between 2 different files, and for some reason it doesn't take to one at all, but does the newly created file.

Comment: on Windows delete chache files found typically here C:\Users\You\AppData\Local\Temp\blender_a*

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for how to clear the animation cache and this is the top hit in my search engine.  After looking further I found this.

https://youtu.be/Ho8bUwGMs3I?t=57

Here is the relevant bit.

[image: Clear cache]

The drill down for this is:

```
Data Properties (Pane) 
  > Scene Properties (vertical tab) 
    > Rigid Body World (section) 
      > Cache (section) 
        > Delete All Bakes (button)
```